# Best possible design for a database about users, companies and departments

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have an app with Postgres and two tables: `users` and `companies`.
A user belongs to a company so a `company_id` column is present on the `users table`. Now a company can have multiple departments so the user maybe will be assigned to a department or no.

What is a  possible database design to avoid multiple joins? I was thinking to have a "pivot" table, `companies_departments` with the columns `(company_department_id, department_id, company_id)`, and another one `companies_departments_users` with the columns `(company_department_id, user_id)` but it involves a lot of joins there.

Can you suggest something?

Comment: *"What is a possible database design to avoid multiple joins?"* Why do you want to avoid joins? The JOIN operator is a very powerful tool in most SQL database management systems. The objective of a design exercise should be to reflect the informational requirements of relevance with high accuracy, not avoiding certain data manupilation operations. If the informational requirements demand performing lots of JOINs, so be it, and in such a case the responsability of the designer should be to optimize their execution at the physical level (e.g. with proper indexing, convenient DBMS settings, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider adopting party-role-relationship model , or a part of it.
Adding concept of Party which can be person, organization, department, application, agent allows you to keep all relationships between different entities in one table. 
For instance, a simplified version can look like

```
PartyTypes(party_type_id,description); -- in many cases you don't even need it , check constraint would work as well since party types are quite static in the context of particular application. 
Party(party_id, party_type_id);
Person (party_id (PK,FK to Party),  attributes specific to Person , like name, date of birth, etc) 
Organization(party_id(PK,FK to Party), attributes specific to Organization) ;
Department (party_id(PK,FK to Party)) ;
RelationshipType(relationship_type_id, description) ;
PartyRelationship(party_relationship_id (PK), relationship_type_id(FK to RelationshipType), party1_id (FK to Party), party2_id(FR to Party), date_from, date_thru);
```

Then , for instance, you create relationship types  "Person to Organization", "Department to Organization", "Person to Department" in  `RelationshipType`  table, which can be used in `PartyRelationship` to specify that a particular person worked for a certain organization or department for some time (date_from and date_thru fields are quite important in real world application) .

The model itself may appear quite complex at first glance, for deep understanding I'd suggest reading Len Silverston book, "The Data Model Resource Book".

Comment: Thanks! Nice approach..